# How to know Flash Player Version from Action Script 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

There is a way to know the flash player version installed on the computer that runs our SWF file with Action Script 3.0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are programming from within the IDE the following will get you the version

```
trace(Capabilities.version);
```

If you are building a custom class the following should help.
Make sure that this following code goes into a file named VersionCheck.as

> ```
> package
> {
>     import flash.system.Capabilities;
>
>     public class VersionCheck
>     {
>         public function VersionCheck():void
>         {
>             trace(Capabilities.version);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Hope this helps, always remember that all of the AS3 language can be studied online here http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/.

Answer (score 4):

It's in [flash.system.Capabilities.version](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#version)

Answer (score 4):

This example might help figuring out the details you receive so that you can act on specifics within the somewhat awkward data you get.

```
import flash.system.Capabilities;


var versionNumber:String = Capabilities.version;
trace("versionNumber: "+versionNumber);
trace("-----");

// The version number is a list of items divided by ","
var versionArray:Array = versionNumber.split(",");
var length:Number = versionArray.length;
for(var i:Number = 0; i < length; i++) trace("versionArray["+i+"]: "+versionArray[i]);
trace("-----");

// The main version contains the OS type too so we split it in two
// and we'll have the OS type and the major version number separately.
var platformAndVersion:Array = versionArray[0].split(" ");
for(var j:Number = 0; j < 2; j++) trace("platformAndVersion["+j+"]: "+platformAndVersion[j]);
trace("-----");

var majorVersion:Number = parseInt(platformAndVersion[1]);
var minorVersion:Number = parseInt(versionArray[1]);
var buildNumber:Number = parseInt(versionArray[2]);

trace("Platform: "+platformAndVersion[0]);
trace("Major version: "+majorVersion);
trace("Minor version: "+minorVersion);
trace("Build number: "+buildNumber);
trace("-----");

if (majorVersion < 9) trace("Your Flash Player version is older than the current version 9, please update.");
else trace("You are using Flash Player 9 or later.");
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Not necessary but helpfull