# How to set the minimal flash player version

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm publishing a swf using ActionScript 3.0 on the web. Therefore, only Flash player 9 or above can run my swf. How can I set the minimal version requirement so that if the use can be notified if his player doesn't meet my requirement?

Comment: How you are building the project? With Flash Builder?

Comment: Yeah, I build it with Flash Builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. As was written in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121453/how-to-know-flash-player-version-from-action-script-3-0), you can get users flash player from `Capabilities.version` ([documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#version)).  The result of this function would be something like this

> WIN 9,0,0,0  // Flash Player 9 for Windows

This is a string so i think with like like this

> var numbers:Array = version.split(" ")[1].split(",");

you can get the array like `[9 0 0 0]`. From this point I think it should be obvious how to compare if users flash player is good for your flash or not.

So if it's not, I usually show a picture which says that user need to install new version of the flash player. And if user click on it, I send him to the [adobe web page](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/).

**Update**

One more way in a case if you are using SWFObject to embed your swf. You can set the minimum version there. official docs [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf663fe-7fff.html).

Comment: If adobe flash builder is used then there is far easier way. The checking, redirecting to download page if minimum version is not meet all can generated using flash builder.

Comment: yes, good point, but this method should work with any IDE/platform/OS/etc, so I think it's fair to post it here.

Comment: I have not said it's not fair, neither I have said this is wrong or downvoted it. I am just saying that there might be easier alternatives.

Comment: and i sad that you have a good point in your comment) I think you should add you alternative way as an answer (and I'm almost sure OP using flash builder, so your answer would be more helpful for him)

Comment: No flame please (just kidding :-P). Actually I have made a comment on the question asking about this. Do not want to add answer without being sure. And as we have already discussed this here, you can add that in your answer too if OP is using flash builder. That will be better than adding another answer.

Comment: Thanks! Very nice answer. Both methods are suggested. I think the SWFObject is the best choice!

Answer (score 3):

i think [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) is the best solution - although it requires JS to be available in the client's browser. w/ SWFObject you could also check if the client got flash installed at all (and show alternative content if necessary)